# gVim: open new empty tab or open the buffered files in a new tab

Tags: vim

Anyway to open a new empty tab to open there the buffered files?

Or is there any way to open the bufferend files in a new tab instead of the current-visible one?

Answer (score 17):

- to open an empty buffer in new tab:  `:tabnew`
- to open an existing
  buffer in new tab:  `:tab sb[bufferId]`
- to open an file in new tab: 
  `:tabe file`
- to open the same file in new tab `:tabnew %`

Comment: Is there a keyboard shortcut for this?

Comment: @philipoghenerobobalogun you can create your own mappings

Answer (score 2):

`:tabe %` will open the same

`:tabe filename` will open a new tab to file.

I like the command t plugin

https://github.com/wincent/Command-T

then its `\t` to search files in cwd and below and `\b` to search buffers. Control T opens a new tab.

Answer (score 1):

You can open a new tabpage for every buffer:

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_every_buffer_in_its_own_tabpage